# Is there CSS to expand the gallery limit on Index Pages?

Tags: php, css

On a wordpress index page, I am only allowed to add 12 galleries. I would like to add many more. Is there a way that I can expand the gallery limit allowed on index pages?

If this is not possible, is there a way that I can add multiple index pages to a folder page?

Thank you for any help